# How to bind Android RadioGroup's RadioButton with MVVMCross

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I would like to bind a click command on an android radiogroup radiobutton using MVVMCross. I was wondering if there is an example that I can follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ApiExamples project has a RadioGroup sample:

```
<MvxRadioGroup
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:textSize="40dp"
 local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_radio"
 local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;SelectedItem SelectedItem"
 />
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/Resources/Layout/Test_RadioGroup.axml

Comment: Actually local:MvxBind = "Click My Command"  works just fine for the radiobutton inside the radio group. Thanks Stuart anyway.

Comment: any idea for the following related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448865/capture-selected-radiobutton-from-the-radiogroup